# How is this serialized value destroyed? How can I debug it to retrieve the data?

Tags: php, serialization

How come this serialzed data is destroyed?

```
a:7:{i:0;a:9:{s:3:"col";s:1:"3";s:3:"row";s:2:"14";s:6:"size_x";s:1:"1";s:6:"size_y";s:1:"8";s:4:"type";s:5:"image";s:3:"url";s:69:"/files/images/5c6ece7dd9db456f528ab42e47953c2b.jpg";s:8:"image_id";s:24:"image_860160127282142600";s:7:"caption";s:7:"En test";s:7:"gotourl";s:17:"http://google.com";}i:1;a:6:{s:3:"col";s:1:"1";s:3:"row";s:2:"11";s:6:"size_x";s:1:"2";s:6:"size_y";s:2:"13";s:4:"type";s:8:"facebook";s:15:"facebookPageUrl";s:30:"https://www.facebook.com/page";}i:2;a:7:{s:3:"col";s:1:"3";s:3:"row";s:1:"7";s:6:"size_x";s:1:"1";s:6:"size_y";s:1:"7";s:4:"type";s:7:"textbox";s:6:"header";s:39:"Drag'n'drop billeder, video, tekst m.m.";s:4:"text";s:224:"Hos os skaber vi et intuitivt og effektivt værktøj til rådighed. Det gør det nemt for institioner og organisationer at opbygge indbydende og flotte skræddersyede profiler, til sine potentielt kommende studerende. ";}i:3;a:7:{s:3:"col";s:1:"3";s:3:"row";s:1:"1";s:6:"size_x";s:1:"1";s:6:"size_y";s:1:"6";s:4:"type";s:5:"qoute";s:6:"header";s:60:"Fremhæv vigtig information, på en indbydende og nem måde.";s:9:"underline";s:8:"EduKarma";}i:4;a:5:{s:3:"col";s:1:"1";s:3:"row";s:2:"24";s:6:"size_x";s:1:"2";s:6:"size_y";s:1:"8";s:4:"type";s:6:"people";}i:5;a:6:{s:3:"col";s:1:"1";s:3:"row";s:1:"1";s:6:"size_x";s:1:"2";s:6:"size_y";s:2:"10";s:4:"type";s:5:"video";s:8:"videoUrl";s:43:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vid";}i:6;a:6:{s:3:"col";s:1:"3";s:3:"row";s:2:"22";s:6:"size_x";s:1:"1";s:6:"size_y";s:2:"10";s:4:"type";s:3:"map";s:7:"address";s:27:"Glssss";}}
```

This editor: http://pines.sourceforge.net/phpserialeditor.php says it is invalid.

**UPDATE**
Serialized data is updated, was not exactly what was received at first. Still not working though.

Comment: Come on, down vote? What is the reason for that? I have tried for more than an hour to figure it out, the only option I have now, is to get help from my fellow developers. I am totally lost.

Answer (score 1):

If you run it through `unserialize`, the output is `Error at offset 201 of 1552 bytes in php shell code on line 1`. Basically, the serialized data is malformed.

[The PHP serialise format](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/classes_objects/serialization.html) is very strict. The fact that you data cannot be restored usually means the string has been modified after generation. If you have been manually modifying the seralize string, you probably shouldn't use that format. Consider something like JSON for a simpler, less-strict format.

Comment: I thought so too, about the length. So I have checked everything in the serialize editor, but I really cant find any mistakes in the string....

Comment: I misread the serialized data – every even value is the value, and the odd ones are the keys. If you are able to recreate the data, try serializing and immediately unserializing the value to make sure it's serializing correct (it should be). That way you'll know whether it's something external breaking the format!

Comment: Can you help me figure out, what is wrong in the serialized string?

Answer (score 0):

You should use function unserialize to check this string. If return false mean that. Your string is wrong serialized and cant be unserialized.

```
$result = @unserialize($yourString);

if($result === false){
 echo 'i`m wrong serialized';
}
```

Comment: OK. But wouldn't there be some way to fix it? I mean, just because it says false, it should still be able to manually fix it, or?

Comment: Could you possible help me figure out, what is wrong with the serialized string? I have been comparing and debugging for more than 1 1/2 hour now :O